# C# Deserialize JSON returns null

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON file test.json with values:

```
{
    "version": "13.5.3",
    "mas": {"users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "password": "123",
        "role" : "client"
      }
    ]},
    "jsonDataFile": {
        "created": "2020-02-29T15:05:22+0000",
        "usersCount": 1
    }
}
```

Have this Class file:

```
public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
}

public class Mas
{
    public List<User> users { get; set; }
}

public class JsonDataFile
{
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public int usersCount { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public Mas mas { get; set; }
    public JsonDataFile jsonDataFile { get; set; }
}
```

And this Program.cs file:

```
string fileName = @"somepath\test.json";
Mas mas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mas>(File.ReadAllText(fileName));

foreach (var item in mas.users)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item.name);
}
```

When i start program - it returns me deserealize.Mas.users.get returned null.

But same json file withous "version" and "jsonDataFile" works good. Where did i make a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deserialize using RootObject as type parameter :

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
```

now get to your desired data :

```
Mas mas = result.Mas;
```

Comment: yea. i forgot about RootObject. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize to **RootObject** like,

```
RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
Mas mas = result.mas;
```

Comment: Many people post the same answer, but i am glad that being helpful :) @AskAlexandria

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
  String fileString File.ReadAllText(@"test.json");
  JObject ex = JObject.Parse(fileString);
  Mas mas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mas>(ex["mas"].ToString());
```

if you want whole Root object

```
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(fileString );
```